# I have a problem on calling a futture<bool> method in a FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter

It works perfectly fine from other devices, but when I switch to a particular device, the future method that I created is not being executed on the futurebuilder

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(_simCard.length>0){
      return FutureBuilder<bool>(
          future: checkID(_simCard),
          builder: (context,snapshot){

            if(snapshot.hasData){
              print(snapshot.data);
              if(snapshot.data){
                //print(currentSimCard.number+"asdasdas");
                flutterTts.stop();
                // Navigator.push(
                //   context,
                //   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage(currentSimCard)),
                // );
                return HomePage(currentSimCard);
              }
              else{
                _container = intro();
                return introBuild();
              }
            }
            return  Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          });
    }
    else return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);

  }

Future<bool> checkID(List<SimCard> simcard) async {
    for(int i = 0; i < simcard.length;i++){
      final snapShot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(simcard[i].number).get();
      if (snapShot.exists){
        currentSimCard = simcard[i];
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }
```

I know the fact that this method is not called by the future builder because when I print the data it will print null

Comment: change to this
`if(snapshot.hasData){return Text(snapshot.data);}else return Container();`. seee what UI you get.

Comment: does not work also, the method does not return any data and I don't know why

Comment: and by the way, I updated the flutter sdk. but it doesn't seem to effect it because it is not working  also  before I upgraded the sdk

Comment: so what the UI displayed now after changing the line I mentioned? Does it return an empty `Container`?

Comment: I just updated the code above

Comment: you can add some print function in `checkID`/ or in each `if-else` block.

Comment: it prints :) but no return :(

Comment: put the print inside `if-else` block. See which line it executed .

Comment: inside of the loop no print but the length of the simcard is 2

Comment: I only have an if statement and it will return true other wise false